# How do I pevent users from manually using the js .submit() function to submit a form, without disabling javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I have an HTML5 form that uses HTML5 form validation for all, except one field, which uses ajax on a regular (not submit) button, labeled "Submit".

with the ajax, once that field has been validated, it uses javascript's `.submit()` to submit the form. in development, the form also has an `onsubmit` attribute, currently set to `return false;` for testing.

Problem I'm having is that all of my validations (except the reCaptcha), and the form's `onsubmit` are being completely ignored when a bot, or person uses the `.submit()` function from the browser's developer console. This was tested, by using the `.submit()` function on the dev console to submit an empty form.

When submitted using the button I assigned as submit, the form works perfectly as intended. What I want to do is limit submits only to the designated button.

I've searched online over and over again, and can't find a way to fix this problem.

I've tried using the `onsubmit` attribute, including `return false;`, expecting the form submit to be stopped, but it was not. If I can find out how to actually stop the form from being submitted with anything other than my designated button, then I can fix the remainder of the problem. Disabling js isn't really an option, because js is required just for the site to function.

the form code below is a very stripped down version, which also excludes the recaptcha element, and the actual validated element (for security reasons). Please excuse the messy code.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="example_action_page.php" onsubmit="return false;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name:<span class="required">*</span>
            </td>
            <td id="name_field">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40" value="" class="inputWidth" required>
                <a class="info" href="javascript:null;">
                    <img src="/images/tip_small.png" border="0">
                    <span class="infobox">
                        How should we address you?
                    </span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Email:<span class="required">*</span>
            </td>
            <td id="email_field">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="40" value="" class="inputWidth" required>
                <a class="info" href="javascript:null;">
                    <img src="/images/tip_small.png" border="0">
                    <span class="infobox">
                        We need this to reply to you.
                    </span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input name="contact_us" id="saveForm" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="return validation_function(element-to-validate);">
                <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot stop users from doing anything with client-side code

Comment: You could pre validate on the server with an ajax call, if valid generate a token and save it in a session. Then add the token to the form and check the token when the form is posted. If the token is wrong or the form is not valid, don't do anything with the submission. This would only be a solution for bots that don't run js.

Comment: Use a php page and use php [validation filters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)...

Comment: @dalelandry your suggestion sounds kinda like the only other option I came up with, which was to basically have the processor itself do a final validation check, after the form is submitted, to make sure all required fields are filled in and valid. Was hoping I didn't have to take this extra step, but it looks like this is the only option. Thanks.

Comment: @NickMaroulis Thanks for the suggestion, but it looks like the bots are indeed using javascript to submit the form, so extra PHP validation it is.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by changing the button back to a proper submit button, and returning to the form, with an error.

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_POST['formName']) and isset($_POST['subTest'])) {
        echo "You are not allowed to submit this form, using javascript.";
    }
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="example_action_page.php" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="hidden" id="subTest" name="subTest" value="submitted">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name:<span class="required">*</span>
            </td>
            <td id="name_field">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40" value="" class="inputWidth" required>
                <a class="info" href="javascript:null;">
                    <img src="/images/tip_small.png" border="0">
                    <span class="infobox">
                        How should we address you?
                    </span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Email:<span class="required">*</span>
            </td>
            <td id="email_field">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="40" value="" class="inputWidth" required>
                <a class="info" href="javascript:null;">
                    <img src="/images/tip_small.png" border="0">
                    <span class="infobox">
                        We need this to reply to you.
                    </span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input name="FormName" id="saveForm" type="submit" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).